# Devise - Recoverable (Password Reset)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise

I am trying to allow the user to reset their password using Devise's **recoverable** option. This doesn't seem to be working for me.

I extend the `Devise::PasswordsController` so that it doesn't use the application layout.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  layout false
end
```

In my routes, I ensure that my passwords controller is used.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:passwords => "passwords"}
resources :passwords
```

Here's my User model so you see that I have the `:recoverable` option.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

On my login page, I have (I'm using haml):

```
...
= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name)
```

This link correctly takes me to `http://localhost:3000/users/password/new`.Here is the form that is found there:

```
%h2 Forgot your password?
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { :method => :post }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions"
```

However, this seems to try to take me to the wrong place when I click the button. It's failing every time, and not showing any emails in the server log.

It's redirecting me to: `http://localhost:3000/passwords/user` and telling me:

**Routing Error**

```
No route matches "/passwords/user"
```

Any idea how I can proceed? I thought using the **recoverable** option was meant to be easier than this. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
For the record, I just removed everything I did, and tried using the standard devise controllers, and I modified my application layout so that it wouldn't cause an error, and everything is working. So I just need a good way to remove the application layout from the password reset page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that when you call `password_path(resource_name)` in your view code, the routing system thinks you mean `/passwords/resource_name`, rather than the controller namespaced under `users` by Devise. This is because you have the line

```
resources :passwords
```

directly under your `devise_for` call in your routes file. Now I'm not sure if that line is there for a reason, but does your problem go away when you comment it out?

Comment: The problem remains. It won't let me access the reset password page without it. It'll complain that there isn't a route for the users/password/new. I originally thought that too, I found that information here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: I think the main issue is the fact that I'm trying to extend the Devise::PasswordsController. I wish I didn't have to do this, the only thing I want is for the reset password page to not use my application layout.

Comment: For the record, I just removed everything I did, and tried using the standard devise controllers, and I modified my application layout so that it wouldn't cause an error, and everything is working. So I just need a good way to remove the application layout from the password reset page.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of whoever finds this old thread and wants some pages to have a different layout, I use this method in my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb to strip out the default layout.

```
<% if ( current_page?(what_ever_path)) %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>      

<% else %> 
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know this is/was an old comment, but you can very easily override devise's layout by creating `app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb` layout file of your own.

Comment: Thanks for that comment and update to this info.  I did not know that bit of rails-magic at the time of my post.